# How to select a custom serilaizer for a particular field of a model in below scenario

Tags: java, json, spring, annotations, jackson

below are two custom date serializers:

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class DateFormatter extends StdSerializer<Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat sampleFormatOne= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");


    public DateFormatter(Class<Date> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public DateFormatter() {
        super(Date.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonGenerationException {
        java.util.Date inputDate = new java.util.Date(date.getTime());

        jsonGenerator.writeString(sampleFormatOne.format(inputDate));
    }

}
```

Also there is another serializer for date:

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class DateFormatterTwo extends StdSerializer<Date> {

      private SimpleDateFormat samoelFormatTwo= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");y");

    public DateFormatterTwo (Class<Date> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public DateFormatterTwo () {
        super(Date.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonGenerationException {
        java.util.Date inputDate = new java.util.Date(date.getTime());

        jsonGenerator.writeString(samoelFormatTwo.format(inputDate));
    }

}
```

Spring configuration is as below:

```
<beans:bean id="customDate"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <beans:property name="objectMapper">
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
                <beans:property name="serializers">
                    <beans:array>
                        <beans:bean class="test.DateFormatter" />
                        <beans:bean class="test.DateFormatterTwo" />
                    </beans:array>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
                <beans:ref bean="customDate" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Now what I need to do is create a *JSON* object that does serialization of date based on f`irst or second formatter` depending on the value of field value employeeType.

With current implementation I could generate a JSON with fixed first format. **How can a serializer be selected at run time based on another field value. ?**

Following are the fields in model

```
private field String employeeType;

    @JsonProperty("empJoiningDate")
    @JsonSerialize(using=DateFormatter.class)
    private Date empJoiningDate = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the *empJoiningDate* field serialized with a format depending on the *employeeType*, you would need to create a custom `Serializer` for the `Employee` POJO type instead of the `Date` field.

Following this approach, you will have access to all the object fields and may provide your conditional date serialization logic.

The `Serializer` implementation would be something as follows:

```java
private static class EmployeeSerializer extends StdSerializer<Employee> {

    private static final String TYPE_ONE = "SomeType";

    private static final String TYPE_TWO = "SomeOtherType";

    private SimpleDateFormat sampleFormatOne = /** format initialized **/;

    private SimpleDateFormat sampelFormatTwo = /** format initialized **/;

    protected EmployeeSerializer() {
        super(Employee.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Employee employee, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeString(employee.getEmployeeType());
        switch (employee.getEmployeeType()) {
            case TYPE_ONE: jsonGenerator.writeString(sampleFormatOne.format(employee.getEmpJoiningDate()));
            case TYPE_TWO: jsonGenerator.writeString(sampelFormatTwo.format(employee.getEmpJoiningDate()));
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

You would then need to annotate your `Employee` value class with your custom serializer instead of the instance date field:

```java
@JsonSerialize(using = EmployeeSerializer.class)
public class Employee {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs, Let me try this out , Now one question, where do I put the annotation  " @JsonSerialize(using=EmployeeSerializer .class)" ? On class in place of field ? Thanks for the info @tmarwen

Comment: Hey Sanyam, as you have guessed it should be the Employee class which should be annotated.
I've updated the answer accordingly to provide a full configuration explanation. Don't hesitate to accept and upvote the answer if it suits your needs.

Comment: hey that worked fine thanks alot :) Also you can upvote my question if you liked it

Comment: Hi, but this modified all values to the same date value , employtee type , empJoiningDate as well :( @tmarwen

Comment: How could all the values be the same? Could you update the post with what you have already tried?

Comment: sure I will post, I think I know the reason now ? JSON writer does not know which field it is writing, since I am annotating class and not filed. I need to explicitly write all properties in the serialize method. let me post it np :)